# DELETE that has multiple optional parameters with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a DELETE Action Method in a Web API controller that relies on multiple nullable parameters.

**Here is how I am currently doing it:**

```
[HttpDelete("{id}?productId={productId}&categoryId={categoryId}")]
public void Delete(int Id, int? productId = null, int? categoryId = null)
{
    _ppManager.Delete(Id, productId, categoryId);
}
```

Is this correct? I figured a DELETE is more similar to a GET than a POST so I used the query string technique since they need to be nullable.

Comment: Do you have any particular problem with that? Describe your need better please.

Comment: You shouldn't put query string parameters in your route; they're handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and this [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1920979.aspx?Web%20Api%202%20preview%20and%20Attribute%20Routing%20allowing%20querystrings%20) the URL parameters are automatically routed to your action parameters that match by name, so you can put it just like that:

```
[HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
public void Delete(int Id, int? productId = null, int? categoryId = null)
{
    _ppManager.Delete(Id, productId, categoryId);
}
```

and the matching URL parameters are going to get routed automatically.